# How to count the number of queries in a queryset that has been filtered and append that number as an attribute to another model?

Tags: python, django

I'm new with Python and Django.  I have three models Post, Vote and VoteModel:

```
class Post(VoteModel, models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Vote(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote_choice = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)      #0 - none, 1 - yes, 2 - no
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class VoteModel(models.Model):
    num_vote_yes = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
    num_vote_no = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now, I want to calculate the total number of yes and no votes for each post.  I do it like this:

`yes_votes = Vote.objects.filter(post=post_instance, vote_choice=1).count()`

I want to save the `yes_votes` number in the abstract `VoteModel` class `num_vote_yes` attribute. How?

I want to access `num_vote_yes` and `num_vote_no` by `post_instance`.`num_vote_yes` and `post_instance`.`num_vote_no`.

Certainly, every time I create a new instance of a Vote class I want the `num_vote_yes` and `num_vote_no` to be automatically updated. How?

Been struggling for a long time now but I learned a lot!  The time has come to outreach! Thanks!

Comment: No, you don't want to "save the numbers in the abstract Vote class". That doesn't make sense. You want to [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) the votes count when you query the data for display. In fact you don't need the Vote class at all.

Comment: Why would you want to save this separately if it can be fetched from the `Vote` table? You should **never** save data to your database that can be calculated directly. It only will give you synchronisation issues and data integrity issues.

Comment: Daniel and dirkgroten are perfectly right and I would have wrote the exact same thing if they hadn't already. What you're trying to do leads to [denormalized db schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), with all the issues it creates. Now there _are_ cases where denormalizing a schema makes sense (ie when computing derived values from the normalized schema is too costly to meet requirements), but 1/ you have to be fully aware of and accept the consequences (stalled or inconsistent data etc) AND 2/  you should only resort to this if and when you __really__ need it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Maybe you mean `VoteModel` class. I think `Vote` class is neccessary which is used to record user vote information.

Comment: Give these men a medal!  Thank you people.  I removed the VoteModel class and, instead, I created a manager method like so `def num_vote_yes(self, post):
        return self.filter(post=post, vote_choice=1).count()`  but isn't it very inefficient to re-filter allll the votes for a particular post everytime a new vote instance comes in?

Answer (score -1):

If you want access `num_vote_yes` and `num_vote_no` just by the `post` instance, you can just put these two fields on your `Post` model. Also you do not need a `Abstract` model. If you can accept to use relation name to access these two fields, you can create a `VoteStat` model and have a [One-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) with Post.

For auto update vote stat info, you can use [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save) signal, when you save vote model, then udpate your vote relative post stat info.

Here is demo example which just put these stat fields in post model you can refer, please note the [`F expression`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f) in the post save function, which can avoid race condition when udpate vote stat info (Of course, you can use `transaction.atomic` and [`select_to_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) to implement this).

Note these links just for `django 2.2`, you can switch to your used version.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # stat info
    num_vote_yes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_vote_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Vote(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote_choice = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)  # 0 - none, 1 - yes, 2 - no
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Vote)
def update_post_vote_stat(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        post = instance.post
        if instance.vote_choice == 1:
            post.num_vote_yes = F('num_vote_yes') + 1
            post.save(update_fields=['num_vote_yes'])
        elif instance.vote_choice == 2:
            post.num_vote_no = F('num_vote_no') + 1
            post.save(update_fields=['num_vote_no'])
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: This isn't the way to do it. Why would you have those fields as columns in the table, where they are repeated for every row?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just like I say in my answer, you also can use a new model to create a one-to-one relationships to save space, here just a demo to show how to implement access `num_vote_yes` and `num_vote_no` just with post instance.

Comment: @DanielRoseman And If dirkgroten's word ` You should never save data to your database that can be calculated directly.` is always right, I think maybe my answer is totally wrong.

Comment: `Now, I want to calculate the total number of yes and no votes for each post.` The author say he want stat for each post. Maybe I understood wrong from begin. Feel confused now, hope the author can make it clear.─.─||